# Compute the general solution for the given system of differential equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Compute the general solution for the given system
of differential equations.

$$\frac{d}{dt}X=\begin{bmatrix}-1 &-4\\ 2& 3\end{bmatrix}X$$

Comment: i know that x(t)=r1e^(lamba1*t)v1+r2e^(lamba2*t)v2

Comment: i know lamba = [2+i*sqrt(12)]/2

Comment: I get that the eigenvalues are Gaussian integers, $a \pm bi$ with $a,b \in \mathbb Z.$ As a result, diagonalization is fairly easy, you can find a (complex) matrix $P$ with $P^{-1}AP = D$ diagonal, so $PDP^{-1} = A,$ so $e^{At} = P e^{Dt} P^{-1}.$ You should finish that.

Answer (score 0):

Set
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -4\\
2 & 3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Compute $Z=L^{-1}({(sI-A)^{-1}})$ in which $L$ denotes the Laplace transform ans $I$ is the identity matrix($2*2$). If your initial value is $x_{0}$ your answer will be:
$$x(t)=Z*x_{0}$$

Answer (score 0):

The problem

$$ \frac{dX}{dt} = A X $$

Can be solved in the following way:

Be v1 and v2 the eigenvectors of A:

$$ A v_i = \lambda_i v_i $$

And be U the matrix whose columns are v1 and v2. Then,

$$ A U = \Lambda U $$

where $ \Lambda $ is the matrix with the respective eigenvalues in the diagonal.

If $ U^{-1} $ is the inverse of $ U $, whe can define $ X' = UX $, and write the original equation as

$$ \frac{dU^{-1} X}{dt} = U^{-1} A X = U^{-1} A U U^{-1} X $$

or

$$ \frac{d X'}{dt} = U^{-1} A U X' $$

But $ U^{-1} A U = \Lambda $, such that we have

$$ \frac{d X'}{dt} = \Lambda X' $$

And the problem can be solved in a decoupled way:

$$ X' = exp\left(\Lambda t\right) $$

Finally:

$$ X = U^{-1} exp\left(\Lambda t\right) $$